# Неизвестное подчеркивание в режиме адаптивности

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Перешел к настройке адаптива на разных разрешениях экрана, как только перешел в режим адаптивности (F12--Toggle device toolbar), появилось неизвестное подчеркивание. Если выйти из инструмента разработчика, то на сайте данной полосы нет. Что это может быть ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.touch{
 background-color: #010101;
}

.touch-title{
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 95px;
 padding-bottom: 45px;
}

.touch .title__main{
 font-size: 32px;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #fcdb00;
}

.touch .title__text{
 color: #898989;
 width: 780px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 24px;
}

.form__input{
 width: 580px;
 padding: 14px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding-left: 24px;
 margin-right: 21px;
 outline: none;
}

.form__btn{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background-color: #fcdb00;
 border-radius: 6px;
 padding: 14px;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 700;
 width: 126px;
 outline: none;
}
.footer{
 background-color: #000;
 padding-top: 55px;
 padding-bottom: 104px;
}

.credits{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 16px;
 width: 184px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="touch">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="touch-title">
              <h2 class="title__main">
                Keep in touch with us
              </h2>
              <p class="title__text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vitae eros eget tellus tristique bibendum. Donec rutrum sed sem quis venenatis.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-10 m-auto">
            <form action="#" class="form text-center">
              <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your name" class="form__input" required>
              <button type="submit" class="form__btn">SUBMIT</button>
            </form>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
     <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="credits">
              HALOVIETNAM LTD
              66, Dang Van ngu, Dong Da
              Hanoi, Vietnam
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: На Вашем примере полоса не воспроизводится. Может сделаете расширенный пример, включающий всю страницу.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Я добавил еще footer. Когда запустите код, разверните фрагмент на весь экран, чтобы открылось на новой вкладке. Затем перейдите в инструменты разработчика, где можно выбирать разные разрешения экрана. Как только начинаете уменьшать разрешение, то появляется сразу эта полоса

Comment: масштаб в браузере 100%?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ т.е. ? Вы про то,когда появляется данная полоса ?

Comment: @Famous неа, не воспроизводится

Comment: 1. Код при уменьшении разрешения не адаптируется, что-то накосячено. 2. Это не похоже на подчеркивание, скорее на бордер. Такая фигня случается иногда при округлении браузером пикселей - погрешности накапливаются однонаправленно и в результате пиксель-другой пропадает/появляется. 3. Такое случается когда масштаб в браузере или в системе нестандартный стоит.

Comment: @Famous так отмечается нижняя граница действия тега